# How to replace all char except number [0-9] using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

How to replace all char except number [`0-9`] using Javascript?

This is my code,

```js
function test_fn(xxx) {
  var xxx = xxx.replace(/[^0-9,.]+/g, "");
  document.getElementById("fid").value = xxx;
}
```

```html
<input onkeyUp="test_fn(this.value)" id="fid">
```

But when user fill `012345...` my code can not replace dot [`.`] 
How can I do for replace dot [`.`] too ?

Comment: Should 'comma' be replaced as well?

Comment: You want at most 1 dot `.` or no one ?

Answer (score 17):

If you only want to keep numbers, then replace everything that isn't a number \d = number.

```
function test_fn(xxx) {
  var xxx = xxx.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  document.getElementById("fid").value = xxx;
}
```

The possible regular expressions to use are:

```
/\D/g     //\D is everything not \d
/[^\d]/g  //\d is numerical characters 0-9
/[^0-9]/g //The ^ inside [] means not, so in this case, not numerical characters
/[^0-9,\.]/g   //. is a wildcard character, escape it to target a .
```

The g means to match all possibilities of the search, so there is no need to use + to match anything else.

You'll find [this tool](https://regex101.com/) very useful when working with regular expressions and it has an explanation of the possible characters to use at the bottom right.

Comment: @Nina Scholz - He doesn't want the dot.

Comment: You could use `\D` instead of `[^\d]`

Answer (score 3):

Change your regex to the following:

```
var xxx = "12.3te.st.45";
xxx = xxx.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
alert(xxx);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/891n0hx0/

This way it removes anything that is not 0-9.

Comment: Use SO code snippet instead of JsFiddle, use the [<>] button for that. It's more readable and more easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the dot and comma out of the regular expression.

BTW, you could just take the element (`this`) as parameter and update the `value` property. With this pattern, you could use the function for other inputs as well.

```js
function test_fn(element) {
    element.value = element.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input onkeyUp="test_fn(this)" id="fid">
```

Comment: i can fill this 121.99900 why not replace dot

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" value="" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use regex if you're not comfortable with.
Here is a non regex version easy to understand.

```
var str = "12AGB.63"
str = str.split("").filter(function(elem){
  return parseInt(elem)
}).join("")
```

split function with "" as parameter will transform Array to String.

join function with "" as parameter will transform String to Array

Here is a description of Array.prototype.filter :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter